# limit execution time of jquery load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jquery load function like below :

```
$("#desc").load("./desc.php?shopcode="+encodeURIComponent(shopcode));
```

I want to limits the maximum time (3 seconds) that the function can take to load desc.php .for example,if the function doesn't load till 3 seconds then it should stop loading of desc.php and gives prompt to user something like "Try Again to load".Any help will be highly useful

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method doesn't provide a timeout option directly.

You have two options:

**1. Use [`ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to globally set a timeout before running your `load()`:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 3000
});

$("#desc").load("./desc.php?shopcode="+encodeURIComponent(shopcode));
```

**2. Use the lower-level [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method where you can specify the timeout**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./desc.php?shopcode="+encodeURIComponent(shopcode),
  dataType: "html",
  timeout: 3000,
  success: function(data) {
    $("#desc").html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate. but unfortunately its not working.I will prefer the first method if it can be somehow implemented

Comment: How is it not working? The timeout will cancel the ajax request after the specified timeout. Of course you still need to setup an error handler to display any error message if you want.